# Excel_prefixed with 0 and how to concatenate those columns in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, concatenation, prefix

https://www.icts.uiowa.edu/confluence/display/REDCapDocs/Preserving+Prefixed+Zeros+in+Excel
with the help of the above link i prefixed the 0 in excel.

Now i want to concatenate these columns A &B to C.

Please let me know how to do that.

```
Example:
column A      column B           column C
06789         00054              Expected: 0678900054
                                 Actual:   0678954
```

Comment: What's your current formula? What are formatting settings for C?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that concatenating numbers is actually concatenating the underlying number (6789 and 54 in your example) not the formatted string.

You can do what you want using:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1,"000000"),TEXT(B1,"000000"))
```

where "000000" is the formatter you applied.

Comment: My question is, if they are `numbers` how are they displayed with leading 0's in the first place?

Comment: @Raystafarian Indeed the example values above has to be text values. Numbers can't be displayed with leading zeros. And since they are just text values, you can also use `=A1+B1`

Comment: @nixda right, or `=A1&B1`